# Xpath java - query with multiple conditions

Tags: java, xpath

I am trying to extract from xml file names of all the people from "XYZ" group who voted AGAINST resolution with signature "A9-309". I have tried several queries by I have no idea how to combine these three conditions in one. Here is the structure of the file:

```
<Vote.Result Id="56" Date = "2021-3-21">
    <Vote.text>
        <a href="resolution-9-309-8">A9-309</a>recommendation 01
    </Vote.text>
    <Results.For>
        <Group Identifier="ABC">
            <Group.member id="102">George</Group.member>
            <Group.member id="12">Diana</Group.member>
            <Group.member id="27">Anna</Group.member>
            <Group.member id="32">James</Group.member>
        </Group>
        <Group Identifier="XYZ">
            <Group.member id="11">Frank</Group.member>
        </Group>
    </Results.For>
    <Results.Against>
        <Group Identifier="ABC">
                <Group.member id="2">Gregory</Group.member>
                <Group.member id="3">William</Group.member>
            </Group>
            <Group Identifier="XYZ">
                <Group.member id="7">Theresa</Group.member>
            </Group>
        </Group>
    </Results.Against>
</Vote.Result>
<Vote.Result Id = "89" Date = "2021-3-21">
```

.... etc.

e.g. this
`//Vote.Result/Vote.text/a[contains(., 'A9-309')]/text();` would give me the vote, or
`//Vote.Result/Results.Against/[@Identifier='XYZ']/Group.member/text();` would give me all members of XYZ group who voted AGAINST any vote.

How to combine these three? obviously, there are many `<Vote.Results>` in the file, so this is why there is a problem.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//Vote.Result[Vote.text/a[contains(., 'A9-309')]]/Results.Against/Group[@Identifier="XYZ"]/Group.member/text()
```

to return one text node: `Theresa`.  Introduce a predicate (expression in square brackets) whenever you want to filter that particular axis of the expression.  Predicates can be nested as shown in the example.

Comment: David, thank you very much for looking into it. At first when I try it, I get null, but will look at it during the day to see what it is I do wrong...